# Pandas Groupy take only the first N Groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some DataFrame which I want to group by the ID, e. g.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'user_id': [1,2,1,1,3,1,5]})
print df
```

Which generates:

```
  item_id  user_id
0       a        1
1       a        2
2       b        1
3       b        1
4       b        3
5       c        1
6       d        5

[7 rows x 2 columns]
```

I can easily group by the id:

```
grouped = df.groupby("item_id")
```

But how can I return only the first N group-by objects? E. g. I want only the first 3 unique item_ids.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just filter the df first? `df[df['item_id'].isin(df['item_id'].unique()[:3])].groupby('item_id')`?

Comment: @firelynx I agree. I had not found that result

Comment: Iterate over first 3 groups.`for n,(k,gg) in enumerate(list(g)[:3])` where g is a instance of `groupby`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is one way using `list(grouped)`.

```
result = [g[1] for g in list(grouped)[:3]]

# 1st
result[0]

  item_id  user_id
0       a        1
1       a        2

# 2nd
result[1]

  item_id  user_id
2       b        1
3       b        1
4       b        3
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a good idea. Due to some constraints a used a random query in the end.

Comment: This instantiates all of the groups in a list when you only need the first 3, so it's extremely inefficient for large `DataFrame`s.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use `Counter` to get the top 3 unique items from the list, filter your DataFrame based on those items, and then perform a groupby operation on this filtered DataFrame.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(df.item_id)
most_common = [item for item, _ in c.most_common(3)]

>>> df[df.item_id.isin(most_common)].groupby('item_id').sum()
         user_id
item_id         
a              3
b              5
c              1
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a good idea. Due to some constraints a used a random query in the end.